# PHP MySQL - Dynamic page with Carousel , images

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic

I want to make a dynamic page, now what I have is a database and in that database only images are inserted and now I can fetch the image and video but i have another images that are inserted and i want to insert it into the carousel how can I do that?

here is my database

[image]

I have fetched `id 1` but the rest of the image from `id 2-3` is not fetched in the carousel. all I want is to fetch the remaining images on the carousel. how can i do that thanks.

```
<?php
  $data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pax_safeties WHERE id='1'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($data);
    if ($count != 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
         echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-5" role="tabpanel"><br>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6 col-md-6">
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExample" target="_blank">

<img src="images/pal/'.$row['paxsafety_image'].'" width="100%">

<div class="modal fade" id="basicExample" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">

<!--------------------CAROUSEL INSERT IMAGES WITH NULL VALUES  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------->

   <div id="carousel-example-11z" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-11z" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#carousel-example-11z" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/pal/safety.jpg" alt="First slide">
     </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-11z" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-11z" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
   </div>
<!--------------------END OF CAROUSEL INSERT IMAGES WITH NULL VALUES  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-md-6">
<img class="watch-video" src="images/pal/safetyvid.jpg" width="100%"> 
  <video oncontextmenu="return false;" class="embed-responsive-item" id="video" allowscriptaccess="always" width="0%" controls controlsList="nodownload">

  <source src="images/pal/'.$row['paxsafety_video'].'" type="video/mp4" width="0%">

  </video>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>';
        }

      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has `WHERE id='1'` so it will only fetch that image and video. If you want to get more results, you need to change that; either remove it to fetch *all* results, or perhaps something like

```
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

i.e.

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pax_safeties WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)");
```

If you want to show *all* images and videos, just remove the `WHERE` condition completely i.e.

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pax_safeties");
```

However this might give you too many results in the future, so you will probably want some form of `WHERE` clause eventually, or possibly a `LIMIT` clause to limit the number of results returned e.g.

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pax_safeties LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: thanks for the info but what if i will add more images? then the `WHERE id IN(1,2,3)` will not be practical .. :( is there a way on how to automatically add images so that the carousel dynamically add images without inserting the id `1,2,3` in the equery?

Comment: @obitouchiha I was just using that as an example. If you remove the `WHERE` clause it will return all the images in the table, however you may run into problems with having too many. See my edit.

Comment: okay just help me with this one sir last question what if I want to get the first row id only how can i do it with this ? `$row['paxsafety_image']` let's assume that i want to get the image of id 1 and my query is selected into all

Comment: If you just want to get the first row (I assume this has minimum id) you could use `SELECT * FROM pax_safeties ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: no i mean can it be like this ? `$row['paxsafety_image'][1]` ?

Comment: Since you are overwriting the values in `$row` in each pass of your loop, you would need to save the value of `$row['paxsafety_image']` in the first pass. Something like `if (!isset($image)) $image = $row['paxsafety_image'];` should work

Comment: `$row['paxsafety_image'][1]` how about this? will it work?

Comment: No that won't work as you only ever have one set of values (for one specific `id`) in `$row`.